# Extract manifest files of an installed application

Tags: android, android-manifest, reverse-engineering

I am trying to develop an android application, which extracts the manifest file of other application and displays it. Is it possible to import the apktool.jar into libraries and extract the manifest? Or please guide me of how exactly to proceed with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is apktool-lib to decode xml resources from an apk, but I've never tried it personally, and it is a bit outdated.

You can find it here: https://github.com/tony19/apktool-lib